# Find out which moderator approved comment?

Tags: admin, comments, comment-meta

Is there any way to find out what moderators have approved a comment, and then display that information on the front-end?

e.g.

John says: "This is a great article"
- Approved by Admin1

Comment: This kind of data is not saved natively. So you will need to start capturing and storing such info first.

Comment: *sigh* I thought so alright. I really need to get myself a developer :( Thanks for the help Rarst!

Comment: @Rarst would we be talking hooking into something like:  `add_action('comment_unapproved_to_approved', 'comment_approved');`

Comment: @Martin no idea, hadn't looked at code. There are multiple ways that comments are dealt with (admin, notification emails, XML-RPC) and I am not sure how hookable all of it is.

Answer (score 8):

To record the moderator that approves the comment:

```
function wpse_comment_moderator_log( $comment ) {
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();

    update_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID, 'approved_by', $current_user->user_login );
}
add_action( 'comment_unapproved_to_approved', 'wpse_comment_moderator_log' );
```

To display it after the comment text:

```
function wpse_display_moderator( $comment_text, $comment ) {
    $approved_by = get_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID, 'approved_by', true );
    if ( $approved_by ) {
        $comment_text .= " - Approved by $approved_by";
    }
    return $comment_text;
}
add_filter( 'comment_text', 'wpse_display_moderator', 99, 2 );
```

Comment: +1 @Hameedullah, i was just building the display function for my effort.. comforting to know for a learner like myself that my record function is almost exact to yours so i was on the right track....

Comment: Glad we both are on right track, as I am myself still a learner.