# Who approved a comment, to show up in dashboard

Tags: comments, moderation

About 10 years ago (!) this message was posted
[Find out which moderator approved comment?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21497/find-out-which-moderator-approved-comment)

That perfectly works but I would like the "Approved by [---]" to show up in the "comments" of the dashboard for all who have rights to moderate comments.

Any suggestion?
Thank you!

Comment: By the "comments" on the dashboard do you mean the dashboard widget? Or the comments page? Or somewhere else

Comment: The "comments" page where moderators can see all comments, pending and approved.

Answer (score 0):

Well finally I found, just added a test on "who" reads the comments. If the reader has moderation rights, the "moderator's name" shows up, in the admin section AND in the post page. There is probably another way to do it, but that's ok for me!